# How do default values and union types work in React components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I described my question with examples here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-diffie-hs57tc?file=/src/App.tsx

So basically I wonder why does setting the default value to a prop break a condition for types.
And the second question is why does passing children as a prop work with types fine but when calling children function in JSX it doesn't see correct types.

That's a tricky question, tried to find an answer in google, but didn't manage it :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a little with your sandbox and figured out a few things.

## `.defaultProps`

*First of all I'd like to precise I just found it may be deprecated in the future, but it works...*
For defining default values to props, you can use the `defaultProps` static field:

```tsx
type Props = {
  flag: boolean;
};

const MyComp = ({ flag }: Props) => <p>{flag ? "Yes" : "No"}</p>;

MyComp.defaultProps = {
  flag: false
};
```

## `React.FC<>`

I noticed that when we remove the `flag` in the first usage of the component, the same problem as the second appears. But I managed to fix it by adding the type `React.FC<ComponentProps>` to the component:

```ts
const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({ flag, children }: ComponentProps /* You can remove the parameter type from here if you want*/) => {
  // ...
};
```

Now, this code tell that `isOpen` does not exist, instead of both the "`title` and `isOpen` are `any`" thing:

```tsx
<Component children={({ title, isOpen }) => <>{isOpen ? title : "Closed"}</>} />
//                             ^^^^^^
// Property 'isOpen' does not exist on type '{ title: string; }'.
```

## The children type inference

About your last question, unfortunately, I didn't found any logical reason, and I think it looks like a React TypeScript bug.

I observed that if we remove the children value we get the following error:

```ts
<Component>{}</Component>
// Type 'never[]' provides no match for the signature '(props: { title: string; }): ReactNode'.
```

So we understand here that TypeScript is aware that the correct type is `children`, and tries to match it. But, for some reason, it is unable to infer the type of the parameter when we give the function. You can, as a workaround, strictly type it and it'll work (but I admit this is not a good solution)...

It seems that it cannot do the type inference with this syntax and in my opinion, you should open a bug report because this is not the correct behavior.